# list all xml nodes to one dimension array?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

List all node as element of an array?
my xml data:

```
<videos>
   <video>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Video 1</title>
    <thumbnail>1.jpg</thumbnail>
   </video> 
   <video>
   <id>2</id>
    <title>Video Number 2</title>
    <thumbnail>1.jpg</thumbnail>
   </video>
   <video>
    <id>3</id>
    <title>Video Number 3</title>
    <thumbnail>1.jpg</thumbnail>
   </video>
  </videos>
```

I want to list all node of xml as element of array.

Who can give me the solution.?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xml2array (http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/) you can do this

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, there are many node_to_array functions in the DOM Document http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php . If you just need nodes->values nested then it can be very simple.